# Javascript/JQuery Dynamic UL Troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a problem adding dynamic UL and LI's to a webpage through javascript and jQuery and am stumped.

I almost have a solution but it's not adding the styling and it is not putting each UL on a separate line. I have a feeling that the tags I am creating are not closing but I'm not sure.

My end goal is to have each JSON line as a separate UL and showing on a separate line, with the first name + last name + phone number as the list items of each UL and displaying like a table (without using a table). No inline styles and no HTML markup other than whatever is added dynamically through Javascript.

I was given the following code as a starting point but my solution has definitely veered a little off course. I have searched for hours and so far you can see my best attempt at the jsfiddle link below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function showContacts(data){
    var markup = "";
    $("body").html(markup);
};

$(document).ready(function myFunction() {
    var jsonText = '[ {"firstname":"Bill","lastname":"Gates","phone":"123-456-7891"}, {"firstname":"Steve","lastname":"Jobs","phone":"198-765-4321"}, {"firstname":"Kevin","lastname":"Spencer","phone":"007-008-0099"}, {"firstname":"David","lastname":"Zimmerman","phone":"800-256-6321"}, {"firstname":"Bert","lastname":"Ernie","phone":"127-624-1138"}, {"firstname":"Guy","lastname":"Lafleur","phone":"806-797-4213"} ]';
    showContacts(jsonText);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bkweLctq/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed `element` creation.
Your `odd` & `even` class style also needs to be changed.

**Updated js**

```
function showContacts(data) {
    var markup = "";
    var jo = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(jo);

var $body = $('body');

var _html = '';

    for(var i = 0; i<jo.length; i++){
        if((i+1)%2 == 0 ){
            _html += '<ul class="even">';
        }else {
            _html += '<ul class="odd">';
        }

        var _index = 0;
        $.each(jo[i], function(k,n) {
            if((_index+1)%2 == 0 ){
                _html += '<li class="even"> '+ n +' </li>'
            }else {
                _html += '<li class="odd"> '+ n +' </li>'
            }
            _index++;
        });
        _html += '</ul>';
    }

    $body.html(_html);
};

$(document).ready(function myFunction() {
    var jsonText = '[ {"firstname":"Bill","lastname":"Gates","phone":"123-456-7891"}, {"firstname":"Steve","lastname":"Jobs","phone":"198-765-4321"}, {"firstname":"Kevin","lastname":"Spencer","phone":"007-008-0099"}, {"firstname":"David","lastname":"Zimmerman","phone":"800-256-6321"}, {"firstname":"Bert","lastname":"Ernie","phone":"127-624-1138"}, {"firstname":"Guy","lastname":"Lafleur","phone":"806-797-4213"} ]';
    showContacts(jsonText);
});
```

[I have also updated your fiddlejs link](https://jsfiddle.net/bkweLctq/2/)

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!